# Audit trail - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Is it advisable to use Triggers in SQL Server to implement Audit trail on very frequently updated tables which contains large data? Are there any performance impacts? If not recommended, what are the options for implementing Audit trail?

Comment: Yes it is, but what detail you have to store in your audit trail ? http://www.softcodearticle.com/2012/11/imlementing-generic-audit-trail-trigger-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Hiten004 thanks. It should be just the inserted/updated row in its entirety and few additional columns - to denote the activity performed and user id kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate Change Data Capture.  It is native sql server functionality for audit logging.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx

CDC does add overhead, but it is well though-out overhead.  Triggers can get messy very quickly and should be avoided when possible.